# Send header Location:mailto... with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, mailto

I try to hide my e-mail address on my public website. The idea is to to show a link to a (internal) page that then redirects to a mailto link.

With PHP the redirecting page would look like this:

```
<?php
  header('Location: mailto:mymail@example.com');
  exit;
?>
```

Is there a counterpart in Rails for redirecting to a mailto link?

Comment: have you tried just placing `redirect_to 'mailto:mymail@example.com'` in a controller method or adding something like `get '/send_email', to: redirect('mailto:mymail@example.com')` in your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @engineersmnky, just `redirect_to 'mailto:mymail@example.com'` did the trick.